# django data migration dependency on contrib.sites

Tags: django, migration, django-1.7

I want to add the sites to the dependencies for one of my data migration.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('jianguo', '0004_auto_20141006_1534'),
        ('django.contrib.sites', '__first__'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_site)
    ]
```

But I got

```
ValueError: Dependency on unknown app: django.contrib.sites
```

Anyone did this before? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ran into the same problem. Apparently you have to omit the 'django.contrib.' when referring to models/apps from the `django.contrib` name space.

Replace `'django.contrib.sites'` => `'sites'` when referring to the `django.contrib.sites` in `dependencies` or when using `apps`.

Comment: I think I tried this, but with no luck. I will try it again later.

Comment: I get: LookupError: No installed app with label 'sites' when attempting this. 'django.contrib.sites' is in my INSTALLED_APPS. How did you get it to work?

Comment: this solution is not working at all